# Applications of quarks or string theory?

Tags: string-theory, standard-model, applied-physics

We wouldn't have computers if we didn't know about quantum physics. I understand understanding of general relativity is needed to make GPS work well. Has knowledge of quarks or string theory resulted in useful things?

**EDIT:** I suspect quarks and string theory could be used by people who study traces of the Big Bang and similar topics. That aside have they resulted in technological advances that could be useful to people (besides improving our understanding of nature)? Perhaps advances in medical imaging have been possible. There might also have been improvements in nuclear fission, nuclear fusion.

Other than that I will be surprised to hear of applications. I suspect many applications are possible, but I expect it will take years to get there.

Comment: I am told that the holographic principle is being applied to cuprate superconductors with some success.

Comment: The edit does make the question better but unfortunately, it's still too broad because there isn't a "correct" answer.  There is a long list of varying degrees of answers which isn't a good fit for this site.